# Como inserir uma TAG com Vírgula ou Ponto e Vírgula

Tags: jquery

achei este projeto para inserir TAGS num formulário, mas ele só adiciona a TAG quando tecla enter, e quando isso acontece no meu formulário ele já envia! Eu gostaria de saber o que devo fazer no SCRIPT para que ele adicione a TAG toda vez que eu inserir virgula ou ponto e virgula....

Formulario exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código SCRIPT:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('#addTagBtn').click(function() {
                $('#tags option:selected').each(function() {
                    $(this).appendTo($('#selectedTags'));
                });
            });
            $('#removeTagBtn').click(function() {
                $('#selectedTags option:selected').each(function(el) {
                    $(this).appendTo($('#tags'));
                });
            });
 $('.tagRemove').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
            $('ul.tags').click(function() {
                $('#tags-field').focus();
            });
            $('#tags-field').keypress(function(event) {
                if (event.which == '13') {
                    if ($(this).val() != '') {
                        $('<li class="addedTag">' + $(this).val() + '<span class="tagRemove" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">x</span><input type="hidden" value="' + $(this).val() + '" name="tags[]"></li>').insertBefore('.tags .tagAdd');
                        $(this).val('');
                    }
                }
            });

  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Melhor é esquecer essa idéia de teclado e analisar a string textualmente, para evitar estes problemas:**

- Incompatibilidade de mapas diferentes de teclado (outras línguas)
- Incompatibilidade com dispositivis de acessibilidade
- Tratamento falho de copy & paste

...e outros mais.

Mas se quiser insistir em usar keycodes, vamos lá.

A linha que detecta o <kbd>enter</kbd> é esta:

```
if (event.which == '13') {
```

O Código do <kbd>enter</kbd> é `13`, você pode colocar outras condições:

```
if (event.which == 13 || event.which == 59 || event.which == 188  ) {
```

Mas é importante notar que este código seu analisa KeyCodes, e não caracteres. Isto pode ter alguma variação dependendo do mapa de teclado utilizado.

Note também que eu tirei as aspas, não entendo a razão do código original fazer comparação com strings.

Para falar bem a verdade, para isto que você quer, seria melhor buscar um *script* diferente, ou adaptar este para se basear na *string* e não na tecla pressionada. Por exemplo, a tecla <kbd>enter</kbd> do numérico já não funciona nele.

Aqui tem ferramentas para testes online:

https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode

https://keyjs.dev/

Faça o teste com teclas do teclado numérico e do teclado principal para entender melhor o problema. Teste também com teclados ABNT2 e internacionais, e vai perceber que o código muda.

Comment: Mal posso ver seus movimentos :p

Comment: @jbueno ainda que eu demorei pra achar a ferramenta kkkkk - De qq forma, upei a sua, tb está correta.

Comment: Eu só achei estranho que pra mim o código deu **191**. Já dá pro AP ter uma noção de que isso pode ser variável

Comment: Seu teclado é ABNT2?

Comment: Sim, é ABNT2. Eu realmente estava vendo isso depois que li sua edição.

Comment: O próprio browser pode dar diferença.

Answer (score 2):

É neste trecho

```
$('#tags-field').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == '13' || event.which == '191' || event.which == '188') {
        //...
    }
});
```

**13** é o código da tecla enter, troque para **191** que é o código do ponto-e-vírgula ou **188** que é o código da vírgula.

Como (bem) notado pelo Bacco, tome cuidado porque isto valida o código da tecla pressionada e não o carácter propriamente dito, logo, está sujeito a variações.